# Tomcat WebSocket error

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I followed this [link](https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774) to make websocket server using tomcat.
When I tried to access the websocket my firefox said it can't establish a connection.

Here is my code

```
public class WsChatServlet extends WebSocketServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static ArrayList<MyMessageInbound> mmiList = new ArrayList<MyMessageInbound>();

@Override
protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string) {
    System.out.println("CreateWebSocketInbound()");
    return new MyMessageInbound();
}

private class MyMessageInbound extends MessageInbound
{
    WsOutbound myoutbound;

    @Override
    protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("onBinaryMessage()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {            
        System.out.println("Accept Message : "+ cb);
        for (MyMessageInbound mmib : mmiList)
        {
            CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(cb);
            mmib.myoutbound.writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Hello!"));
            mmib.myoutbound.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
        System.out.println("onOpen()");
        try {
            System.out.println("Open Client.");
            this.myoutbound = outbound;
            mmiList.add(this);
            outbound.writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Hello!"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WsChatServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClose(int status) {
        System.out.println("Close Client.");
        mmiList.remove(this);
    } 
}
```

Here is the server log

```
24 Apr 13 22:53:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [WsChatServlet] in context with path [/HelloWebSocket] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorRequestWrapper cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
    at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.doGet(WebSocketServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How to solve this problem and how to make the log inside code format?

Comment: If you post your code that would be helpful

Comment: Which tomcat version you are using? I recommend to use apache tomcat 7.0.42 which is quit stable with WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug in Tomcat 7.0.27. I recommend you use 7.0.37, or use a framework like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) (would will be shielded from such problems)

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: +1 on using a framework like Atmosphere or [Cometd](http://cometd.org) even once jsr-356 is live, then you can get benefits from the best protocol supported between browser and server (spdy, websockets, or even http/2 when that lands later this year)

Answer (score 0):

Check your tomcat version. Websockets are not yes standard and different servers have different implementations for websocket. I once used websockets with tomcat and it used to work only with tomcat 7.0.27. It didn't work even with 7.0.29. So I suggest check if you can find which server did your tutorial used or try with different versions.

Comment: I'm using tomcat 7.0.27
Actually what I tried to achieve is a way communicating from mozilla plugin which use javascript with existing java code. Do you have any idea to achieve this without using websocket?